# Run Django development server as public website

Tags: django, web, public

What are the risks of doing this? I understand the documentation says not to do it, but I have password protected all the pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that your "password protection" is useless if a hacker can simply bypass that and read your database directly. We don't know if they can, but - as the docs say - the dev server has undergone *no* security testing whatsoever, so they might well be able to.

Plus, the server is single-threaded. It will only ever be able to serve one request at a time. That makes for a very slow experience for your users.

Seriously, there is *no reason* to do this. Setting up Apache + mod_wsgi, or whatever your preferred hosting environment is, is a five-minute process if you follow the very detailed instructions.

Comment: Can you recommend a detailed tutorial for setting up the apache server?

Comment: Also, is there any risk to my server, i.e. the laptop that is running the website? I am not overly concerned if someone hacked in and got access to my databases at this point.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean, you want to deploy your Django project, you should use something like NGINX etc.

If you just want to tell, what if a development server is public, you have the same risks with any another project written in any platform.